# VS Code weird pasting

Tags: visual-studio-code, hugo

I'm building my site with Hugo and I've noticed weird behavior of VS Code when pasting snippets of codes like:

[the bug displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsNC0.gif)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/style.css" | relURL }}">
```

The first line is typed by hand and it works, the second line is pasted, and as you can see VS Code treats this code differently and it doesn't work. It similar to this:

[bug 2 displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KpAM.gif)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

It breaks the code and won't let the site to render. I have Format On Paste turned off. I'm pasting the snippets from a .epub ebook - Is there a way to paste without any format? Similar to what you can do in Google Docs (ctrl + shift + V)

Comment: use the hex editor to see what the content of the file is after a paste

Comment: Decoded text from hex editor looks like this:
<meta charset="utf-8">..
<meta charset=â.."utf-8"â..>
Do you have any idea why VS Code displays it without any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They most likely are the quote characters that look like the `"`.

Just delete the characters and replace them with `"` and see if that fixes the problem.

Some e-books use a formatting tool meant to be used in novels and it replaces the `"` with the quote characters as if John says: ”BlaBlaBlaBla“

To better see the difference you might try and use a different font that has different glyphs for these quotes.

To replace the *Double Quotation* Marks (U201C and U201D) use extension [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

Add to `settings.json`

```
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "Quotes": {
      "find": ["”", "“", "‘", "’"],
      "replace": ["\"", "\"", "'", "'"]
    }
  }
```

Execute command: **Replace Rules: Run Rule...**

And select: **Quotes**

If you first select part of the file only those parts are searched and replaced.

If needed you can also replace the *Double Prime* (U2033 and U2036) characters. But I haven't seen any eBook that uses them.

Comment: @MatysekM Than you can mark this answer as the solution to the problem